# SingleChildScrollView not working on the full row

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having a `Row` which contains a list of widgets , a `Builder` and a variable that adds new item to the list to be built with the `Builder`.
Anyway , I was trying to wrap the whole `Rows` with `SingleChildScrollView` , but now , every part of my `Row` is scrolling separately .
My `Row` contains two widgets `Expanded()` and inside the `Expanded()` , I got a `itemBuilder`.
I got a button in the bottom that calls two functions , and they will add new `Widgets` to the `List`.

```
    class _ajouterUnDocumentState extends State<ajouterUnDocument> {
  List<Widget> _cardList = [
    (InputRefNomProduit()),
  ];

  List<Widget> _cardList2 = [
    (InputQuntitePrixProduit()),
  ];

  void _addCardWidgetExp1() {
    setState(() {
      _cardList.add(SizedBox(height: 10));
      _cardList.add(InputRefNomProduit());
    });
  }

  void _addCardWidgetExp2() {
    setState(() {
      _cardList2.add(SizedBox(height: 10));
      _cardList2.add(InputQuntitePrixProduit());
    });
  }

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF2A2D3E),
      body: Padding(
        padding:
            EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0, bottom: 60.0, left: 120.0, right: 120.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Card(
            shadowColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
            color: Color(0xFF2A2D3E),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0)),
            elevation: 10.0,
            child: Container(
              width: 1800,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Center(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            "AJOUTER UN FOURNISSEUR",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          Divider(
                            thickness: 3,
                          ),
                          SingleChildScrollView(
                            child: Container(
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    flex: 3,
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 10,
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 530,
                                          width: 500,
                                          child: ListView.builder(
                                              itemCount: _cardList.length,
                                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                                return _cardList[index];
                                              }),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(width: 25),
                                  Expanded(
                                    flex: 3,
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 10,
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 530,
                                          width: 500,
                                          child: ListView.builder(
                                              itemCount: _cardList2.length,
                                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                                return _cardList2[index];
                                              }),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

                          //Membership Widget from the widgets folder

                          Center(
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 400.0,
                                ),
                                MaterialButton(
                                  color: Colors.grey[200],
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Annuler",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 20.0,
                                ),
                                MaterialButton(
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 75, 100, 211),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    _addCardWidgetExp1();
                                    _addCardWidgetExp2();
                                  },
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Ajouter",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is InputQuntitePrixProduit():

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        return Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                width: 25.0,
                child: Text(
                  "$label",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.7,
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: fieldController,
                  validator: fieldValidator,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    hintText: "$content",
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 190, 190, 190),
                        fontSize: 14),
                    fillColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 5.0,
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Container(
                width: 50.0,
                child: Text(
                  "$label2",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 5.0,
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.7,
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                child: TextFormField(
                  enabled: false,
                  controller: fieldController,
                  validator: fieldValidator,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    hintText: "$content2",
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 190, 190, 190),
                        fontSize: 14),
                    fillColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a simplified version of it, `_cardList` items are unknown here.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh : I added an exemple , would you please check it. Thank you.

Comment: You can check more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: you have a row with widgets positioned by expanded flex values.  your scroll from left to right.   Does your new items in the list descend vertically from the row?